# JSON , how to parse variable with "-" name

Tags: json, rest, parsing

I have below json data. Here i m not able to parse "user-1" using script. Its returning null values. any ideas please..

JSON Data:

```
{  
   "users":[  
      {  
         "unique_id":1122774,
         "user-1":"Alpha",
         "user-2":"Beta",
         "location":"ABC",

      }
   ]
}
```

SCRIPT :

```
for (var key in parsed.users) {
 gs.log("unique_id "+parsed.matches[key].unique_id);
 gs.log("user 1 "+parsed.matches[key].user-1); 
}
```

Comment: JSON Data:
{
  "users": 
 [
  {
    "unique_id": 1122774,
    "user-1": "Alpha",
    "user-2": "Beta",
    "location": "ABC",
  }
 ]
}

SCRIPT :
   for (var key in parsed.users) 
   {
    gs.log("unique_id "+parsed.matches[key].unique_id);
    gs.log("user 1 "+parsed.matches[key].user-1);
   }

Comment: parsed.matches[key]["user-1"]

Comment: Please dont put the rest of you question on the comments.  Edit your post to add the additional info you just put on the comments.

Comment: Please dont dump your code in the comments. just edit.